# Trying to change from onclick to onhover

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

So I have a menu at the top of a site that has some drop down menus. The drop down menus are script to show onclick, and I would like to change them to fire the event when you hover the mouse over it.

I believe this is the script for it:
http://babblespot.com/application/widgets/menuadvanced/externals/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js

It has a lot of code on it, the top being mostly jquery I believe.

This is a plug-in, so I am having a little difficulty.

This is the site: 
http://babblespot.com/members/home

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you intend to link directly to jQuery? I'm confused.

Comment: I was looking in the totally wrong place. This is my first time ever using jquery, and i notice that if i disable it. then the drop down menus would also be disable. So I made an erroneous connection. Now the problem is that when you pull away. the menu still stays open. but thats for another time.

Answer (score 1):

Simply switch the `click` with the `hover`. I am not going to list all the changes, but an
example, change

```
$jq('.custom_249').click(function(){
```

To

```
$jq('.custom_249').hover(function(){
```

Comment: thanks, appreciate it greatly. I was going in a totally wrong direction. Feel kinda dumb now.

Answer (score 1):

Your page contains this code:

```
    $jq(document).ready(function(){
                $jq('.custom_249').click(function(){
                    $jq('.custom_249_dropped').toggle('fast');
                });
            });
```

If I understand your question, you need to replace the call to click(), with a call to hover(), as documented at http://api.jquery.com/hover.

Comment: thanks, appreciate it greatly. I was going in a totally wrong direction. Feel kinda dumb now.